# Can't get values from db in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i use CodeFirst to get db vaues to my properties in Model

**Controller**

```
     public ViewResult List()
     {

       EFProductRepository rep = new EFProductRepository();
       IEnumerable<Product> values =  rep.P();

        return View(values);
    }
```

**Model**

```
      public class Product
      {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

      }

    class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

**Web Config**

```
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=FoodStore" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

The Products property count is always 0. How i can get the values from my db ?

Comment: Where is your code to count `Products`? With correct setup you can retrieve `Product` values from DB & count them.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto ,i see products count with debug.

Comment: What is `rep.P()` doing? Please show code.

Comment: @James P ,P is method that just returns Products property.                                                          private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();                                                       
        public IEnumerable<Product> P()
        {
            return context.Products;
        }

Comment: @James P , Yes i am sure,Did you get datas from db?and whats the name of db do you declare?my db is in App_Data folder , but it's not created automatically , i added my db to that folder for myself

Comment: @James P thanks , but did you added db for yourself in App_Data folder or it was created automatically and what you named your db ? should it be the same class name ? i named it EFDbContext as class.

Comment: Did you loop through `values` or call `rep.P().toList()` ?

Comment: rep.P().ToList(); gives me System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException and loop throw values gives this exception - "The context cannot be used while the model is being created. This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe."}

Answer (score 0):

you may have a problem with the connection string . so try the below connectionstring code in webconfig.

```
   < add name="ConnectionStringName"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Mainly include the **AttachDbFileName** it will automatically create the database in the app_data folder.

source:[Set up EF to use a SQL Server Express LocalDB database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

[LocalDB Connection String Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752.aspx#localdb)

Hope it will be helpful

Thanks
Karthik